# Finding extrema: When can you replace $f$ by $\phi\circ f$, or vice versa?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I tried to give the best explaination with the title.

I read in a math site, that if I have a function like:
$$
f(x,y)=\arctan(x^2+y^2+1)
$$
I can only study the argument, because $f(g(x,y))=\arctan(g(x,y))$ and  $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$ have the same **points** of minimum and maximum.

This come from the monotony and continuity of $arctan$ so I can extend this trick also to functions like $e^{g(x,y)}$, $\log(g(x,y))$, $\arcsin(g(x,y))$. Is that correct?

Another question, can I extend this trick to one variable analysis?

p.s.
a detailed explaination of why this works is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: If all you're after are the extreme points, that works. But your title indicates much more generality than that … As a grammatical aside, there is a huge difference between “can study only” (title) and “can only study” (body). I assume you intended the former in both places.

Comment: I'm not english, but what I mean is: can I study the inner function to find the stationary points of the composite function? sorry for the english

Comment: Functional analysis is something different than what you think it means. I've edited to remove that tag.

Comment: Ok in my language it's called like that! thanks